# SQL Insert Query Isn't Working (Update)

Tags: php, mysql

This is an extension of a question I asked yesterday, but I wasn't able to find a solution to my problem. This is my current code, which appears to break on the $result:

```
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'dbuser';
$dbpass = 'password';
$dbname = 'users';
$cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$dbpass,$dbname) or die("Could not connect to server.");

$email = $_POST['email'];
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
        $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
        $safe_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($cxn,$email);
        $safe_username = mysqli_real_escape_string($cxn,$username);
        $safe_first = mysqli_real_escape_string($cxn,$first_name);
        $safe_last = mysqli_real_escape_string($cxn,$last_name);

        $query = "insert into `user_data` (`email`, `username`, `first_name`, `last_name`) values ('$safe_email', '$safe_username', '$safe_first', '$safe_last')";
        $result = mysqli_query($cxn,$query) or die('Can\'t complete query.');
        echo "Congratulations!";
```

I've checked the error report on my site, and it doesn't show any errors created when submitting the form. I have given the 'dbuser' the following privileges for the table: INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, and CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES. I haven't changed any major settings in the database itself.

Comment: Try running the query directly on mysql, and let us know the error message it returns.

Comment: is that a typo in the quotes around `username' in $query?

Comment: print to the insert query and execute it in mysql then you can get a perfect error..

Comment: I noticed that when entering it in phpmyadmin. Fixing that error makes it run perfectly, but the page still gives me the error after fixing it.

Comment: which type of error you got??

Comment: Please include the error that you are getting.